# Selecting a number does not always return a Chinese character with ibus pinyin

Tags: keyboard, ibus, input-method, chinese, pinyin

I use *Intelligent Pinyin Keyboard*<sup>1</sup> with `ibus` in Ubuntu to input Chinese characters into my document.

The `input-method` is designed in such a way that one types the `pinyin` associated with a character, and then one can select it from a list of characters using numbers <kbd>0</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> on the keyboard.

**Example:**

[image]

---

**Problem:** in the last week, it sometimes happens that when I press a number from <kbd>0</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> the input-method does not yield a Chinese character but the digit I pressed instead. Moreover, any further keyboard input is not interpreted as an input for ibus, and merely written as-is on screen until I manually switch input-mode to `pinyin` again.

What I tried, in order:

- reboot
- remove the input method configuration, and add again
- reinstall ibus-pinyin

None of these seemed to help.

**Q:** Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

---

*As a side note, there seems to be a `*ibus-engine-libpinyin.*.crash` file inside `/var/crash` that could be related to this problem. However, I am not sure how can I trace this bug-report online and see if it has already a solution online.*

**edit:** my current workaround is to use `fcitx` instead of `ibus` .. though this doesn't really solve the problem in the software.

<sup>1</sup> *Intelligent Pinyin Keyboard* can be installed by the invocation of the `sudo apt-get install ibus-libpinyin` and can be located in <kbd>All Setting</kbd><kbd>--></kbd><kbd>Text Entry</kbd><kbd>--></kbd><kbd>Input sources to use</kbd><kbd>--></kbd><kbd>+</kbd> as *Chinese (Intelligent Pinyin) (Ibus)*.

Comment: I use _IBus Pinyin 1.5.0_ and _SunPinyin_. What do you mean by the _Intelligent Pinyin Keyboard_? How to install this? What version of _Ubuntu_ do you use?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install ibus-pinyin ibus-libpinyin --reinstall`?

Comment: See pt. 3 of my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `rm ~/.cache/ibus/libpinyin/*`

**Long answer:**

I have similar problem except my problem is not able to return any Chinese character in next column **>**.

The first thing I do is run `watch -n 3 -d 'ps auxww|tac'`  to compare what's the difference between the output when success(first column) and failure(next column) occur.

I quickly noticed that `/usr/lib/ibus/ibus-engine-libpinyin --ibus` still running on success but disappear on failure.

[image]

That means `/usr/lib/ibus/ibus-engine-libpinyin --ibus` process crash when select character in next column.

Since the previous process is gone, while <kbd>Super+Space</kbd> to toggle new libpinyin process, select the first column, then run `ps auxww` in another terminal to know the latest `pid` is `6798`, run `sudo strace -ff -vvv -p 6798 -s 1000000` to understand the process:

```
[pid  6798] lseek(14, 12288, SEEK_SET)  = 12288
[pid  6798] read(14, "", 4096)          = 0
[pid  6798] write(2, "ibus-engine-libpinyin: ../src/lookup/phonetic_lookup.h:901: bool pinyin::PhoneticLookup<nbest>::train_result3(const pinyin::PhoneticKeyMatrix*, const pinyin::ForwardPhoneticConstraints*, MatchResult) [with int nbest = 3; MatchResult = _GArray*; GArray = _GArray]: Assertion `m_user_bigram->store(last_token, user)' failed.\n", 323) = 323
[pid  6798] mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f59a80e2000
[pid  6798] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ABRT], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  6798] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
[pid  6798] getpid()                    = 6798
[pid  6798] gettid()                    = 6798
[pid  6798] tgkill(6798, 6798, SIGABRT) = 0
[pid  6798] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  6798] --- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=6798, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid  6800] <... poll resumed> <unfinished ...>) = ?
[pid  6799] <... restart_syscall resumed>) = ?
[pid  6800] +++ killed by SIGABRT (core dumped) +++
[pid  6799] +++ killed by SIGABRT (core dumped) +++
+++ killed by SIGABRT (core dumped) +++
```

The strace output stopped after select character in next column. Now I know it's the **core dumped**. Alternative way is debug with `tail -f /var/log/syslog` to know it's `systemd-coredump`.

So I run `coredumpctl list` to know the coredump related `pid` is `6798`:

```
Sun 2018-10-28 06:18:31 +08    6798  1000  1000   6 present   /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-engine-libpinyin
```

I run `coredumpctl dump 6798 --output alamak` to save coredump into alamak file, then run `gdb -q /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-engine-libpinyin alamak`(the executable path can get from `ps auxww` or `coredumpctl list`) to examine the coredump file:

```
xb@dnxb:~$ gdb -q /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-engine-libpinyin alamak
expansion:  History expansion on command input is on.
filename:  The filename in which to record the command history is "/home/xiaobai/.gdb_history".
remove-duplicates:  The number of history entries to look back at for duplicates is 0.
save:  Saving of the history record on exit is on.
size:  The size of the command history is 10000000.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-engine-libpinyin...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New LWP 6798]
[New LWP 6800]
[New LWP 6799]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/usr/lib/ibus/ibus-engine-libpinyin --ibus'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f59a80971c0 (LWP 6798))]
```

Try `thread apply all bt full` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to navigate next page, I can see some interesting keyword which is the same with the previous `strace`'s `write()` output:

```
(gdb) thread apply all bt full

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f59a36a9700 (LWP 6799)):
...
#1  0x00007f59a67cd801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
        save_stage = 1
        act = 
          {__sigaction_handler = {sa_handler = 0x555b8ce58800, sa_sigaction = 0x555b8ce58800}, sa_mask = {__val = {0, 18446744073709551600, 0, 0, 0, 140733365772904, 0, 140733365772736, 140023023567312, 21474836480, 140023023552472, 0, 2476426370025201152, 140023023537428, 0, 140023023552472}}, sa_flags = -1488188568, sa_restorer = 0x7f59a74c0c00}
        sigs = {__val = {32, 0 <repeats 15 times>}}
#2  0x00007f59a67bd39a in __assert_fail_base (fmt=0x7f59a69447d8 "%s%s%s:%u: %s%sAssertion `%s' failed.\n%n", assertion=assertion@entry=0x7f59a74c0c00 "m_user_bigram->store(last_token, user)", file=file@entry=0x7f59a74c0b68 "../src/lookup/phonetic_lookup.h", line=line@entry=901, function=function@entry=0x7f59a74c14e0 "bool pinyin::PhoneticLookup<nbest>::train_result3(const pinyin::PhoneticKeyMatrix*, const pinyin::ForwardPhoneticConstraints*, MatchResult) [with int nbest = 3; MatchResult = _GArray*; GArray = _GArra"...) at assert.c:92
        str = 0x555b8ce58800 ""
        total = 4096
#3  0x00007f59a67bd412 in __GI___assert_fail (assertion=0x7f59a74c0c00 "m_user_bigram->store(last_token, user)", file=0x7f59a74c0b68 "../src/lookup/phonetic_lookup.h", line=901, function=0x7f59a74c14e0 "bool pinyin::PhoneticLookup<nbest>::train_result3(const pinyin::PhoneticKeyMatrix*, const pinyin::ForwardPhoneticConstraints*, MatchResult) [with int nbest = 3; MatchResult = _GArray*; GArray = _GArra"...) at assert.c:101
#4  0x00007f59a7476a71 in pinyin_train () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpinyin.so.13
#5  0x0000555b8c7e5689 in  ()
```

Now the main keyword which causes the coredump has been confirmed, google `const pinyin::PhoneticKeyMatrix*, const pinyin::ForwardPhoneticConstraints*`, will found this [bug report thread](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=891954):

> I ran libpinyin in the terminal and got the following error message:
>
> debian-user:~$ /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-engine-libpinyin --ibus
>   ibus-engine-libpinyin: ../src/lookup/phonetic_lookup.h:901: bool
>   pinyin::PhoneticLookup::train_result3(const
>   pinyin::PhoneticKeyMatrix*, const pinyin::ForwardPhoneticConstraints*,
>   MatchResult) [with int nbest = 3; MatchResult = _GArray*; GArray =
>   _GArray]: Assertion `m_user_bigram->store(last_token, user)' failed. Aborted
>
> So this error is related to the user data. When you select a phrase
>   other than the first one, libpinyin will try to store it in your home
>   folder. If it doesn't work it will fail and exit.
>
> You may want to check the contents in ~/.cache/ibus/libpinyin/ . I
>   simply deleted all files in this folder and kill ibus-engine-libpinyin
>   process to restart it. They things come back to normal again. I think
>   the problem you have is likely to be the same as mine. If not please
>   provide error messages when you run ibus-engine-libpinyin in terminal
>
> ...
>
> I followed your instruction and deleted the ~./cache/ibus/libpinyin
>   folder. The problem solved.

That's it, run `rm ~/.cache/ibus/libpinyin/*`, and it fixed the problem.

Comment: I expecially express my gratitude for explaining in detail how you were able to solve the problem.

Comment: Is there any way to express to the maintainers that this is in fact a pretty severe bug and should be patched?

Answer (score 1):

**1.**

> *Moreover, any further keyboard input is not interpreted as an input for ibus, and merely written as-is on screen until I manually switch
>   input-mode to pinyin again.*

In the `SunPinyin` (with the `ibus` input) you can set the initial state of an output for *English/Chinese.* It does not work on `IBus Pinyin 1.5.0`.

**2.**
At least as a stopgap until the crash is repaired, you can try to use `Google Pinyin`, `WubiPinyin`, `SunPinyin` or `Pinyin` under `fcitx`, which is able to manage the romanized input better.

```
sudo apt install fcitx fcitx-googlepinyin fcitx-table-wbpy fcitx-pinyin fcitx-sunpinyin
```

You need to change the input method for the `fcitx` in the <kbd>System Settings</kbd> <kbd>--></kbd> <kbd>Language Support</kbd> and reboot the system (in my case to log out/log in is enough). Tray icon will show <kbd>keyboard</kbd> (`fcitx`) in place of <kbd>En</kbd> / <kbd>Ru</kbd> / <kbd>Pl</kbd> button (`ibus`).

Then look for `Google Pinyin`, `WubiPinyin`, `SunPinyin` or `Pinyin` in <kbd>All Setting</kbd> <kbd>--></kbd> <kbd>Text Entry</kbd> <kbd>--></kbd> <kbd>Input sources to use</kbd> <kbd>--></kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>, typing *Chinese* to narrow the list.

**3.** (Temporary facilitation) By pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> you can change the input manually as well as punctuation *etc*. Check: <kbd>All Settings</kbd> <kbd>--></kbd> <kbd>Text Entry</kbd> <kbd>--></kbd> <kbd>Input source</kbd> <kbd>--></kbd> <kbd>Preferences</kbd> <kbd>--></kbd> <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd> to assign a proper shortcut.

Comment: @Patrick: What virtual keyboard is in use? I use _Onboard_ for example.

Comment: `fcitx` offers you a virtual keyboard, `ibus` only input sources.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin: I am happy that I could help. My advice: do not remove your comments in the future. The record of our discourse is useful for the future users also if somebody made a mistake.